# Getting Accelerometer values from MPU 6050

Tags: avr, embedded, atmega328p

I m trying to read accelerometer values from mpu 6050 in atmega328p (Arduino UNO). I want an embedded c program that's why don't wanna use any external lib. So I read about I2C protocol, read the datasheet of MPU 6050, register sheet of MPU 6050 and developed a code as per my understanding.
Here's the code

```
#include<avr/io.h>
const int MPU_addr=0x68;
void i2c_init() {
  TWSR=0x00;
  TWBR=0x48;
  TWCR = _BV(TWEN) | _BV(TWIE) | _BV(TWEA);
}

void i2c_start() {
  TWCR=(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTA);
  while((TWCR&(1<<TWINT))==0);  
}

void i2c_stop() {
  TWCR=(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTO);
}

void i2c_write(uint8_t data) {
  TWDR=data;
  TWCR=(1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN);
  while((TWCR&(1<<TWINT))==0);  
}

uint8_t i2c_read(unsigned char isLast) {
  if(isLast==0) {
    TWCR=(1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWEA);
  }
  else {
    TWCR=(1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN);
  }
   return TWDR;
}

int main() {
  uint16_t i;
  i2c_init();
  i2c_start();
  i2c_write((MPU_addr<<1)|(1<<0));
  i2c_write(0x6B);
  i2c_write(0);
  i2c_stop();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(1) {
    i2c_start();
    i2c_write((MPU_addr<<1)|(1<<0));
    i2c_write(0x3B);
    i2c_start();
    i2c_write((MPU_addr<<1)|(0x00));
    i=(i2c_read(0)<<8)|i2c_read(0);
    Serial.println(i,BIN);
  }
return 1;
}
```

The problem is in the while loop, the program hangs after the i2c_start(); call.
I have checked this by putting a Serial.println("a"); after that line, but nothing gets printed on the serial monitor. I have also checked that the program enters the while loop successfully. So can anybody help where is the problem in the code?

Note:
1. All the i2c function(s) are in accordance with the book "The Avr microcontroller and the embedded system using assembly and C" by Ali Mazidi".

Comment: I don't understand -- what is the problem with using a library function in an embedded program? All Arduino programs are embedded programs, whether or not they use library functions.

Comment: Are you handling the interrupt? Since you have enabled the Interrupt for TWI, in the init routine. I guess that was not intended, try removing that and it should work.

Comment: @AbelTom According to what i have read, TWINT bit will not enable interrupt, infact setting TWIE bit will enable enable interrupt.

Comment: @AdityaSingh Yea `TWIE` is the bit i meant which needs to be disabled from TWCR register not `TWINT`. Since you are using a polling based approach, i am not sure what  setting `TWIE` would bring.

Comment: @AbelTom TWIE is set to 0 by default, so i don't need to worry about that i guess.... AND TWINT bit is set by the hardware whenever a particular task is executed. it needs to be cleared by the software by writing 1 to it...

Comment: @AdityaSingh you realise you are setting the interrupt enable bit in the control register with this statement in your init routine right? `TWCR = _BV(TWEN) | _BV(TWIE) | _BV(TWEA);`  Is your code working now?

Comment: @AbelTom oops, didn't notice that..  yes although code does return some value it is of no use. Even when the sensor is disconnected it still prints some value. Also, the value gets never changed, a constant value throughout the run of the program whcih is "11010000"

Comment: @AdityaSingh You also need to check for an acknowledge after start, and only after, send 7 bit address, check for acknowledge from your slave, and so on, you need to check the `TWSR` on your ATMEGA328p for this, its decribed properly step by step in the datasheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [datasheet of the 328p (page 297)](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega328_P%20AVR%20MCU%20with%20picoPower%20Technology%20Data%20Sheet%2040001984A.pdf), it seems like you're handling the TWINT bit wrong.

By the datasheet, the bit is *never* cleared by the hardware, which is what you're seeing. It's set by the hardware instead.

By a quick skim over the code, what you could simply do would be inverting the logic around the TWINT - clearing it to make it do stuff, and waiting for it to become set again.

Comment: thanx for the help. The program finally runs but its now throwing same value continuously(11010000) even when I change the orientation of the mpu board. Any help??

Answer (score 0):

You will learn a lot about device by taking it one step at a time. But before going any further remove that TWIE bit. You are not using interrupts in the rest of your code.

Begin by reading chip ID (6 bits in reg 0x75). When you get it right you'd know your reading function is correct (should be 0x68). Note that what you are reading now in main loop is actually full slave address + read bit (0xD0). Hint: you have to wait for data to come back.

Then do initialization. I see you setting clock source to internal clock. This should work, but in the future I recommend using PLL from any one of the gyros, it is more precise.

But you are not done yet, you have to set up full scale range at least for accelerometer (i'd set it for gyros too).

I am not 100% sure but I think the initialization can only be done while chip is in sleep mode. At least in my own MPU6050 library I keep device in sleep after power-up, do all configuration and only then clear SLEEP bit.

Finally, in main loop reading you do not send NACK after second byte. And you continuously using repeated Start. I'd send NACK + Stop condition at the end of the loop and introduce a delay at least corresponding to selected data rate. It makes no sense to read faster then data can be updated.

The biggest problem with your code, however, is lack of proper handling of the status register, you are checking TWINT only. This actually works, but only in ideal conditions where there are no errors and slave always ACKs.

Comment: I did exactly what you said "Begin by reading chip ID (6 bits in reg 0x75). When you get it right you'd know your reading function is correct (should be 0x68)." But data returned is "11010000" which is D0. Where is the problem???

Comment: I gave you a hint. The response from the slave does not just magically appear in the register. You have to continue clock pulses and wait for slave to send data back. Only after that you reply with either ACK or NACK.